# JavaScript unexplained failure CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, function, dynamics-crm-2013

I have the following applied as a library to a CRM 2013 form

```
    function calcServicePriceTotal() {
alert("Start");//----------HERE
if (document.getElementById("Services")) {
        alert("InsideIf");  //----------HERE
    var grid = document.getElementById("Services").control;
        alert("ThisFar?");//----------HERE
    var ids = grid.Control.get_allRecordIds()
        alert("ThisFar2?");//----------HERE
    for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            alert("InsideFor");//----------HERE
       var cellValue = grid.control.getCellValue('iss_salesprice', ids[i]);
       var number = Number(cellValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
       sum = sum + number;
   }
   Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("ava_tempgrossvalue").setValue(sum);
   alert("Done");//----------HERE
}
else {
    alert("Else");//----------HERE
    setTimeout("calcServicePriceTotal();", 2500);
}
}
```

For some reason I get as far as the `alert("ThisFar?")` line but then nothing else happens.

Does that mean that there is a problem with `var ids = grid.Control.get_allRecordIds()`? I don't know why I'm not at least seeing "ThisFar2".

Can anyone see anything obvious?

Comment: Please provide the error that browser console is logging. There should be some error displayed on the browser console.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala it says "Unable to get property 'get_allRecordIds' of undefined or null reference" but the grid is loaded or else it would not have entered the first half of the IF statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function calcServicePriceTotal() {
    if (document.getElementById("Services")) {
        var grid = document.getElementById("Services").control;
        var ids = grid.get_allRecordIds()
        var sum = 0
        for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
           var cellValue = grid.getCellValue('iss_salesprice', ids[i]);
           var number = Number(cellValue.replace(/\D/g, ''));
           number = number/100;
           sum = sum + number;
       }
       Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("iss_value").setValue(sum);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout("calcServicePriceTotal();", 1500);
    }
}
```

Final working solution